# Refreshing LazyPagingItems without visibly refreshing LazyColumn in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-paging-3, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

I'm using Jetpack Compose and LazyPagingItems to display paged data in a LazyColumn using the Paging 3 library. I have implemented the refresh functionality when the user comes back to the Tab by calling refresh() on the PagingSource.

However, when I call refresh() on the PagingSource associated with LazyPagingItems, the entire LazyColumn refreshes, causing the UI to visibly reload and scroll back to the top. This behavior is not ideal as it disrupts the user experience. I just need the column to update with the new data if there is any.

I want to find a way to refresh the data in LazyPagingItems without letting the user notice any visible changes. In other words, I want to update the data silently in the background.

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val beersRepository: BeersRepository,
) : ViewModel() {

    val state: Flow<PagingData<Beer>> = beersRepository
        .getBeers()
        .flow
        .cachedIn(viewModelScope)

}

//Repository
class BeersRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val beersApiService: BeersApiService,
) {

    fun getBeers() = Pager(
        config = PagingConfig(
            pageSize = 10,
            enablePlaceholders = true,
        ),
        pagingSourceFactory = { BeersPagingSource(beersApiService = beersApiService) }
    )
}

//Paging source
class BeersPagingSource @Inject constructor(
    private val beersApiService: BeersApiService,
) : PagingSource<Int, Beer>() {

    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, Beer>): Int? {
        return state.anchorPosition?.let { anchorPosition ->
            state.closestPageToPosition(anchorPosition)?.prevKey?.plus(1)
                ?: state.closestPageToPosition(anchorPosition)?.nextKey?.minus(1)
        }
    }

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Beer> {
        val page = params.key ?: 1
        return try {
            delay(500)
            val response = beersApiService.getBeers(page, perPage = 10)
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val beers = response.body()!!.map {
                    it.toDomain()
                }
                LoadResult.Page(
                    data = beers,
                    prevKey = if (page == 1) null else page - 1,
                    nextKey = if (beers.isEmpty()) null else page + 1
                )
            } else {
                LoadResult.Error(Exception(response.message()))
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            LoadResult.Error(e)
        }
    }
}


//And finally the Composable
private fun MainScreenRoute(
    viewModel: MainViewModel = viewModel(),
) {
    val pagingItems = viewModel.state.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

    Scaffold(bottomBar = {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.Transparent)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            Button(onClick = {
                pagingItems.refresh()
            }) {
                Text(
                    text = "Refresh", style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge
                )
            }
        }
    }) {
        Surface {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            ) {
                when (pagingItems.loadState.refresh) {
                    is LoadState.Error -> {

                    }

                    LoadState.Loading -> {
                        Surface {
                            Box(
                                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                            ) {
                                Text(
                                    text = "Loading...",
                                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineLarge
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    is LoadState.NotLoading -> {
                        LazyColumn(
                            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
                            contentPadding = PaddingValues(8.dp)
                        ) {
                            items(pagingItems.itemCount) { index ->
                                val beer = pagingItems[index]!!
                                BeerCard(
                                    imageUrl = beer.image,
                                    name = beer.name,
                                    description = beer.description,
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Attempted `refresh()` on `LazyPagingItems`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you cached your `giftsList` in your ViewModel? It should look something like that:

`val giftsList = repository.giftsList.cachedIn(viewModelScope)`

Comment: Caching in Viewmodel doesn't make any difference!
I've added more details to the question.

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: No, you are correct. Caching the data in ViewModel does the trick.

The problem with my code was, I rendered placeholder cards (Shimmers) whenever the load state went to refresh.

What I did to fix the issue was to check for the item count and show the full-screen loader only when the count is 0. In this way, the list is updated if the new data has any changes.

The only issue is with the pagination. If the user has scrolled down a lot, there is an unpleasant scroll to the top. But that is expected, no?

Comment: hmm no it shouldn't happen if you remember the state of the scroll 

Comment: It seems you are correct there as well.
The issue was with the API which returned the previous index as always -1. So, whenever the refresh happened, the pager assumed the current page was the initial one.

Anyways, the fix has to come from the API team.
Thanks.